# Finding units of an expression

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dimensional-analysis, units

Can someone please help me on finding the units of the following expression?
$$\frac{n\sin\theta \sqrt{d^2+(\delta s)^2}}{d}$$

Where $n$ is adimensional, $\theta$ is in radians, $d$ is in meters, $\delta$ is adimensional and $s$ is also in meters.

I don't know how to handle the root thing and if I should consider the $\sin\theta$ as a distance, wich means that it would be in meters as well.

Comment: Note that a radian or a sine is defined as the ratio of two lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an adimensional quantity, times the sine of an angle, which is also adimensional, times the square root of a quantity that is expressed in $m^2$, divided by a quantity expressed in meters. This means you get $\sqrt{m^2}/m$ which is adimensional.